# Why could be a parameter missing on SOAP request?

Tags: xml, vb.net, soap-client

I'm sending data to a SOAP server and added this data.

```
    xEvent.asset = Patente
    xEvent.code = xEvento
    xEvent.date = FechaHora
    xEvent.latitude = Latitud
    xEvent.longitude = Longitud
    xEvent.speed = Velocidad
    xEvent.temperature = Sensor1
    xEventList.Add(xEvent)
```

But when I send the data the date field is missing; not even the tag  appears on the XML.
Could be a bad formatted data that is causing this behavior?

The PDF sent by the server owner says that it need this format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS (2023-06-20T18:25:29) but in the XML example the date appears as 2023-06-20T18:25:29.000

I think I have some similar issue like this post [Parameters in complex type missing from Soap Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923359/parameters-in-complex-type-missing-from-soap-request)

But the answer didn't explain well how to solve it.

Comment: What is the data type of `FechaHora`?  Is it a date time or a formatted string?

Comment: If your date string always closes with a ".000", you could use `xEvent.date = FechaHora.Split(".")(0)`.

Comment: @Hursey Is a String.

Comment: @zx485 Thanks. I'm just trying to point that there's a difference between the date field in the table that explain the format needed and the XML that is given as example.

Comment: @Hursey The compiler is making the conversion because I can read the correct datetime in the properties of xEvent.Date.

Answer (score 0):

There's a property called dateSpecified, I set it to true and now the datetime is in the XML.

Based on the answer in the post [Parameters in complex type missing from Soap Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923359/parameters-in-complex-type-missing-from-soap-request)